# CSS :target pseudo-class is not applied after click on link

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm using Rails5 (with turbolinks)

HTML markup:

```
<a href="/post/slug#target1">Target1</a>
<a href="/post/slug#target2">Target1</a>
...
<p id="target1">Content1</p>
<p id="target2">Content2</p>
```

CSS:

```
p:target {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Problem is that :target pseudo-class is applied only after page refresh. Style is not applied when clicking on links.

I'm almost sure, that this behaviour caused by turbolinks. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution, while writing this question.

To make things work well, we need to add data attribute to such links, as follows:

```
<a href="/post/slug#target2" data-turbolinks="false">Target1</a>
```

This attribute disables turbolinks on per-link basis.

More details here: [Disabling Turbolinks on Specific Links](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links)